# How can I grant ownership of my code to someone else?

Tags: licensing

I have been hired to build a program, however the person who hired me is intended to have appropriate 'ownership' of the code.

I've been looking around, and I am very confused on how this works. Is there a specific type of document I need to find and sign to make everything legal? I'm not finding a lot of good resources concerning any of this. Most of what I find only applies to open source software, which this project is not.

Comment: Your jurisdiction makes a difference to this answer, as may the terms of whatever contract you created this work under.

Comment: It really depends of your country. In France, for example, your contract must mention the "ownership's loss" of the developer ; or the "guided creation" of the project.

Comment: I think what's meant that the IPR stays with the owner, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intellectual_property, and you can not claim any "inventions" you created during your work for the owner (and indeed depends under which law/country the contract is signed)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you have created a [work for hire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work_for_hire).  The person who hired you already owns the code.

Answer (score 1):

Typically you'd sign a work contract which would have a clause about who owns the intellectual property rights to your work output. If it didn't, you and your employer could sign a separate letter that simply states your agreement. In many jurisdictions, there are implied rights determined by the nature of your hiring relationship if nothing is in writing.

Both parties should seek a legal review of whatever you are going to agree to, whether in writing or orally.